# python: reordering the values in a list

Tags: python

I have a list `l = [1,3,4,5,6,2]` and I want to change the order to `[4,5,6,1,3,2]`

I did:

```
l[:2], l[2:-1] = l[2:-1], l[:2]
```

but I got `[4,5,1,3,2]` as a result, why is 6 missing?

Comment: FWIW, I think this problem would be easier to wrap our heads around if the initial list was `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` -- then when we look at the desired re-ordering, it's easier to see how the indices map.

Answer (score 2):

Because `l[2:-1]` has 3 numbers and not 2.

```
l[:3], l[3:-1] = l[2:-1], l[:2]
```